# Installing tensorflow_data_validation is causing error #tensorflow_data_validation

Tags: python, tensorflow-data-validation

I'm trying to install tensorflow_data_validation but it shows the below error.

it says that i need Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ but I'm using the version 3.10.9.

Also I have the 2.11.0 version of tensorflow

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advice

#tensorflow_data_validation #tensorflow_data_validation

[trying to install it in jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irnzu.png)
[installing it in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTmSz.png)

I have tried to install it in cmd and jupyter notebook but it doesn't work in both ways

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the package only promises [support for Python 3.8 and 3.9](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-data-validation/) under the most recent release (April 2023). Secondly, [installation requires specific dependencies](https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation/blob/90c1db4af8536c9c0fbc5445d7efd53ec9922727/setup.py#L178-L205) that may not all match simultaneously with your Python too.

I experienced the same issue under the Kaggle docker image which brings Python 3.10.

But I was able to **install `tensorflow-data-validation` under Python 3.7** though, using their [nightly packages](https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation/blob/master/g3doc/install.md#nightly-packages). Here is the terminal screen of the installation done in a virtual environment:

```
(.test) (base) maciej.skorski@kaggle-cpu-maciej:~$ python --version
Python 3.7.12
(.test) (base) maciej.skorski@kaggle-cpu-maciej:~$ export TFX_DEPENDENCY_SELECTOR=NIGHTLY
(.test) (base) maciej.skorski@kaggle-cpu-maciej:~$ pip install --extra-index-url https://pypi-nightly.tensorflow.org/simple tensorflow-data-validation --quiet
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 23.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/home/maciej.skorski/.test/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(.test) (base) maciej.skorski@kaggle-cpu-maciej:~$ pip show tensorflow-data-validation
Name: tensorflow-data-validation
Version: 1.12.0
Summary: A library for exploring and validating machine learning data.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/data_validation/get_started
Author: Google LLC
Author-email: tensorflow-extended-dev@googlegroups.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/maciej.skorski/.test/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: tensorflow, six, pyfarmhash, joblib, apache-beam, absl-py, pyarrow, protobuf, tensorflow-metadata, tfx-bsl, pandas, numpy
```